# Using JMeter is it possible to wait for all threads to finish before ending the test?

Tags: jmeter

I need to run a jmeter test with N users over the course of a fixed time period. I am planning on using an "Ultimate Thread Group" for this as it meets my requirements. However, at the end of the time period and during the ramp down it simply kills threads even if they are not finished. This causes me problems because I end up in a situation where I have half completed records left lying around. Is there any way, either using this type of thread group or any other type to do as I require?

I have already got my test script ready, and have been exploring different thread groups and UTG seems like the best option, apart from the fact it kills threads without waiting for completion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use stepping thread instead of ultimate thread group, this will surely help you out with your scenario. You can adjust stepping thread parameters according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it seems the stepping thread group is deprecated and so I am reluctant to use it. Also, it looks like it would have the same problem which is that it just stops threads rather than waiting for them to finish